# Checking for character in a string

Tags: if-statement, pascal

I need to check a string, in this case called "word," to see if it contains a letter (or character if you prefer). 
I don't really need to know the location of the letter, simply if it is present. Currently I have this:

```
if character in word then //both "word" and "character" are string variables.
begin
{some code}
end;
```

Trouble is, is that this is just me ripping off a python function:

```
if character in word: //In python I would use an array for "word" 
    //some code
```

And this doesn't seem to work in pascal.

This may seem like a dumb question, but I am very new to pascal and indeed to asking for help on stack exchange. Any help as to how to check for characters in strings would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about [strpos](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strpos.html) or [strscan](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strscan.html)?

Comment: Michael's Those are for pchars, not for strings, and were used in Turbo Pascal days. They are rarely used nowadays, since the normal (object) pascal strings can be cast to pchars for external interfacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if pos(character,word)>0 then
     ... some code
```

pos is overloaded for both characters and strings (for substring matches)

Note that searching is case sensitive. Uppercase() both character and word if you want otherwise.